# Add Multiple Sum Aggregations in Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, query-builder, elasticsearch-2.0, elasticsearch-query

I have a json query version of adding sum of two fields in aggregations like this -

```
 "aggs": {
            "field1Sum": {
                "sum": {
                    "field": "field1"
                }
            },
            "field2Sum": {
                "sum": {
                    "field": "field2"
                }
            }
    }
```

I need to convert my data into this query using Java QueryBuilder for Elasticsearch

So far -

```
 SumBuilder s1 = AggregationBuilders.sum(field2Sum).field(field2);
 SumBuilder s2 = AggregationBuilders.sum(field1Sum).field(field1);
```

Any help?

Comment: Your code looks correct. What do you need?

Answer (score 1):

```
SearchResponse sr = client.prepareSearch()
    .setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery())
    .addAggregation(
            AggregationBuilders.sum(field2Sum).field(field2)
    )
    .addAggregation(
            AggregationBuilders.sum(field1Sum).field(field1)
    )
    .get();
```

[Link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-search-aggs.html)